# Should I write "that being said" (vs. "that's been said" or "Having said that")?

Tags: writing, expressions

I often write what "sounds" right (being not a native English speaker/writer), and I believe the expression "that being said" to be fairly common, as opposed to a more complete form like "that's been said" or "Having said that".

In doubt, I turn to [google fight](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=that+being+said&word2=that%27s+been+said), which seems to confirm the [common usage](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=that+being+said&word2=Having+said+that). (not exactly the right reference, I know.)

Yet, I don't think that "that being said" is correct, especially in writing. "That said" is even more common. Is it also acceptable in writing?

What expression would you use in formal writing? (Not too formal though: like a [technical forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087775/how-do-i-detect-when-output-is-being-redirected/2087817#2087817))

Comment: To me at least to "say" something connotes the act of using your mouth, not your pen (or keyboard). But that's more of a "feeling" for me. Others may argue that you very well *can* "say something in writing"... but then again you may as well state / express / ... something in writing too. I'd prefer sth like: "With that being stated, ......" rather than "said". Would be nice to see a good answer picking up this sub-question regarding the choice of the verb "say", in this context, in a written (and at least semi-formal) form, backed up by some evidence / sources.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty But... ChatGPT tells me that ""Saying" something does not necessarily have to involve the use of one's mouth, as it can also be done through written or typed communication.". And I always trust ChatGPT. ([Ah... crap.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/6309))

Comment: *(Off-topic: Did you actually "ask" ChatGPT that question / did you run a script?)*

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Exactly, I asked the bot. But its answer was a rather conventional one.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Both "that said" and "that being said" are common (possibly *too* common) and perfectly grammatical, and sufficiently formal as well. "Having said that" is also correct, but to be correct the subject in what follows must be whoever said that (usually "I"). For instance, you can say:

- Roses are usually red. That [being] said, they are also…

But you'd have to say:

- I like turtles. Having said that, **I** will now proceed to show…

That said, if you don't follow it up with "I", many people wouldn't notice anything amiss these days.

"That's been said" is a full sentence (edit: complete clause), and it only means "That has been said". Full stop. It cannot be used to introduce the rest of the sentence in the same manner.

Comment: Of course both of those require subjects. It looks to me like the difference is that (1) is a stative predicate ("being said"), so it need not have an agent or causer in subject position. (2) ("having said") is not stative and requires an agent of some kind.

Comment: Yes of course, the sentence still requires a subject... probably I should have said it constrains you to a specific subject. :-)

Comment: What do you think of njd's comment below, about "That's been said" being incorrect?

Comment: @VonC: As njd says, "That's been said" is incorrect when used in the same context as the other two. That's what I also said. As an independent stand-alone sentence, it is fine.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, "Having said that", "that said" and "that being said" actually mean "however". I think that the examples that you gave can mislead us from that meaning. Maybe a more appropriate example would be "I like turtles. Having said that, I would never have a turtle as a pet."

Comment: @Bruno: Good point. I wouldn't agree that they *mean* "however", but they are certainly most often used to introduce a transition, with the same function as "however".

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, yes, you're right, it's to introduce a transition, not exactly "however".

Comment: It's an http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction.

Answer (score 5):

To my ear, "that's been said" is actually wrong if used in this context. The other two, "that being said" and "having said that" are normal; I would say they are somewhat fossilized expressions. However, they aren't ungrammatical. For instance:

1) The car being washed, Hugo went home. (somewhat archaic sounding, but I think fine)

2) Having washed the car, Hugo went home. (perfect)

"That's been said" will sound distinctly odd if used in the same way, probably just because it is not a recognized idiom.

Comment: Actually, I think it sounds odd even without taking into account how common the other expressions are. Consider:

3) * The car's been washed, Hugo went home.

I think this has something to do with the difference in aspect, but I am not sure. Interesting!

Comment: +1. The (a) correct phrasing of (3) would be "The car having been washed, Hugo went home" or "Having washed the car, Hugo went home".

Comment: Wait, I get it. "That's been said" is a passive construction. That's why it would sound so odd.

Comment: Which is to say that it's a complete clause, unlike the other two.

Comment: "That's been said" is incorrect, and is just a mis-hearing of the correct phrase "That being said". Look up http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn

Answer (score 1):

It simply offers more variety. I edit texts and there is only so much repetition of "however" I can take before I start changing things. I really like the Phrase "that being said."

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to use "that being said", "having said that" or any other variation of this faddish hackneyed phrase.  Instead use "however" or "but".

Comment: Yea pure fluff. I can see that 'was said'. It's like saying the tire was round, well duh! When I encounter an article that uses these fluff phrases I usually just stop reading.

Comment: you seem to oppose evolution of the language

Comment: How is stating the obvious an evolution? It's actually easier to say 'however' or 'but', and I don't think those words annoy anyone.

Comment: How exactly are _however_ or _but_ not just as hackneyed? There’s nothing ‘faddish’ about ‘that being said’ etc.; they’ve been used for at least two centuries. And most importantly, **they don’t necessarily mean the same as _however_ or _but_**. They are participial clauses with the verb _say_, and while they are often used concessively, they can also be used literally, similar to ‘having established that’, with no notion of opposition between the preceding and the following content. This answer (1) does not answer the question, and (2) is patently wrong.

Comment: @user3015682 ‘That being said’ is nothing like “saying the tire was round”. Firstly because the latter does not have any kind of concessive meaning, and secondly because the latter is a complete clause (≈ a statement), while the former is not. If ‘that being said’ is “stating the obvious”, then so is _however_ or _but_. But it’s not, because it’s not _stating_ anything at all. It’s taking something (which may indeed be obvious) as the conditioning premise for the actual statement, which is what _follows_.

Comment: Sure it is, both state the obvious, regardless of 'concessive meaning' or complete clause. 'However' is the proper word to use; "used to introduce a statement that contrasts with or seems to contradict something that has been said previously." Saying 'that was said' is just plain silly as we already know that 'was said'. It's an annoying substitute for a well established word.

Comment: Depending on context, this phrase does not necessarily mean the same thing as "but" or "however" to me.