# "That said," "That having been said," or "That being said"?

Tags: grammar, expressions

**That said, the game is over.**

**That having been said, the game is over.**

**That being said, the game is over.**

Are all equally acceptable?

Comment: They're all equally fine garbage filler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I write "that being said" (vs. "that's been said" or "Having said that")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184/should-i-write-that-being-said-vs-thats-been-said-or-having-said-that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All three are acceptable.

**That said** — [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/that_said)

> 1. However
>
> *"Christmas is exploited by capitalism. That said, it is still a religious festival."*

It is a set phrase, kind of idiomatic.

> Synonyms: Be that as it may, Having said that, Nevertheless, That being said

Comment: They are all the same of someone trying to fill the void while trying to move on to a new sentence.

Answer (score 0):

David Pearce is absolutely correct. In fact, “That said”, “That having been said”, and “Having said that” are all equivalent and have been around for centuries. “That being said” is a monstrosity that incorrectly shortens “That having been said” and arose out of the blue in the last couple of decades. Of course, like a lot of linguistic monstrosities, it has promptly spread like wildfire, and even people who wouldn’t have dreamt of saying it in 2000 are dropping it every five minutes in 2020. And yes, “being said” implies simultaneity, while “said” alone is a past participle and synonymous with “having been said”. Bottom line: “being” is incorrect in this phrase, and so is anything beginning with “With”, i.e. “With that being said” is a double monstrosity.

Comment: Is this just your own opinion? Such answers are inappropriate on ELU. And while the use of the expression has certainly snowballed since 2000, there are examples (of << , [up]on that being said, >>) dating back to say 1800.

Comment: No, Edwin Ashworth, it is not just my own opinion. As a professional linguist, I certainly do not believe language is a matter of personal opinion. Yes, I know, language changes constantly, and all language change is initially an “error”. So I am prepared to see this monstrosity win out, like so many others. Thanks for your example from circa 1800, though, which I find very interesting. Notice, however, that “[up]on” implies simultaneity.

Comment: But your opinion is now obviously shown to be at least partly incorrect. ' "That being said” is a monstrosity that incorrectly shortens “That having been said” and _arose out of the blue in the last couple of decades_ ' is false. Other answers, here and at the former related thread, attest to the expression being in use (whether or not answerers actually like the style), and there is no authority referenced claiming that the usage is _incorrect_ (/'ungrammatical'?).  Your claim needs support on ELU. Even John Lawler, a published Professor Emeritus of Linguistics, adds supporting references.

Comment: We’re not talking about ancient history. I don’t know how old you are, but I’m in my seventies and have been a full-time linguist for over five decades. I pay a lot of attention to language and, for many newfangled words and phrases, I can remember the first time I heard them used. So, I can assure you that “That being said” was not in common use prior to about twenty years ago. Educated speakers would say or write “That said” (or “Having said that”), but otherwise the phrase was not in widespread use, and surely not among those less-educated speakers who tend to overuse “That being said” now.

Comment: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that_being_said) sees fit to include the variant 'That being said', without a 'slang' or 'colloquial' flag. While acceptability becomes almost uncontestable when a candidate word or expression appears in say M-W, AHD or Lexico (OED often takes more time to do the research), one needs more than 70 years of experience (which I share) and an Oxbridge education to sensibly challenge such a claim.

Answer (score -1):

if something is said before something else, then "that having been said" is correct, while "that being said" is not. "that being said" means something is being said in the present, whereas "having said that" places the "saying" before the next phrase. regarding the examples below, "being in prison" is different from "having been in prison." "Now that is said and done" means something is currently said and done, like "do Americans say the word elevator and ride in a lift." Now that was said and done would suggest in the past, Americans said elevator and rode in a lift.

Comment: What has been said cannot be unsaid. So if it has been said, it is still said.

Answer (score -4):

"That said" is an appropriate truncation of "that having been said", which is correct in that the clause refers back to what was just stated in the prior sentence. "That being said" is incorrect since the prior sentence is in the past. It is not in the process of being said. That said, "that being said" is still a commonly used idiom.

Comment: There’s no reason at all why “that being said” should be illogical or incorrect. It doesn’t matter whether the thing said was said in the past or in the present, it is still said. It’s completely parallel to “that being the case” or “his brother being in prison”. The present participle does not indicate the progressive aspect here; it is simply the morphological form required to form an adverbial, non-finite relative clause.

Comment: I don't see how "being the case" or "being in prison" is parallel to "being said"? I agree with the anser. I'm not a native speaker though…

Comment: Yes, someone needs to remove David Pearce's reply from Google Answer. It's downright wrong. It would be like saying "Now that is said and done" should be "Now that was said and done". There is no grammatical issue with the former.